# blazor wasm throwing deserialization exception when published

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM application that I publish to a server where it's run as an IIS site.

I've just converted it to .NET 8 and in DEBUG and RELEASE modes it executes just fine on my machine in Visual Studio.

However, when I publish it either as a self-contained app or as a portable app then I get the following exception when it runs one page in the site:

```
aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
2blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The deserialization constructor for type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]' contains parameters with null names. This might happen because the parameter names have been trimmed by ILLink. Consider using the source generated serializer instead.
System.NotSupportedException: The deserialization constructor for type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]' contains parameters with null names. This might happen because the parameter names have been trimmed by ILLink. Consider using the source generated serializer instead.
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.CachingContext.CreateCacheEntry(Type type, CachingContext context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at SmartTools.Client.Pages.BotAnalyserToolsPages.DatabaseComparerBase.CompareAsync()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at SmartTools.Client.Pages.BotAnalyserToolsPages.DatabaseComparer.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_27()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at MudBlazor.MudBaseButton.OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs ev)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.GetTypeInfo(Type , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo.<EnsureConfigured>g__ConfigureSynchronized|172_0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task , ComponentState )
Ft @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Digging into the method that generates the error, I have the following lines of code:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options 
  = new() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> items 
  = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(data, options)!;
```

If I include the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine($"data: '{data}'");
```

And inspect this in the Browser's console, then I see that data is as I would expect, namely:

```
[
  {
    "key" : "some key",
    "value" : "some value
  },
  {
    "key" : "some key",
    "value" : "some value
  },
  ... etc
]
```

If I capture that exact JSON and execute the following in LinqPad

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> list 
= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(dataFromConsole, options)!;
```

then it works absolutely perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of DatabaseComparerBase.CompareAsync() ?

Comment: @HH, I rewrote the issue (seems I missed part of the flow first time)

Comment: I "solved" this by creating a class called "KVP" which had two properties, "Key" and "Value" and by using this in preference to `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.  Okay, I didn't really solve the issue, just dodged it.

Comment: @DrGriff Getting the same issue deserializing with [GetFromJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync).  However if I use the non-generic [DictionaryEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry) it works fine.  I had thought that it might be related to assembly [trimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/trimmode-full) but now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior appears to be a breaking change in .NET 8 as detailed in [A published blazor wasm app throws a serialization error "Unhandled exception rendering component: ConstructorContainsNullParameterNames"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95409).

> No. It means that using reflection-based serialization in trimmed applications is not reliable and can result in multiple failures like the one reported here. This is a problem inherent to using dynamic member access via reflection in trimmed applications and there's not much that can be done about it other than adding manual annotations to work around the issues that pop up. Our recommendation is to switch to the source generator if you must use a trimmed app, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/reflection-vs-source-generation?pivots=dotnet-8-0) for more details.

and

> The fundamental issue is that trimming and reflection are fundamentally incompatible. There's nothing that we can do about this in the System.Text.Json layer other than recommend switching to the source generator which is trimming-safe.

However like the OP I also had the same problem when I tried to disable trimming by setting `PublishTrimmed` to false.  I'd encourage others to comment on that issue if  trimming is disabled and encounter the same exception.

Comment: I don't have the `<PropertyGroup>` setting `<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>true</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>` so I believe that I'm experiencing this without trimming.

Comment: The exception is getting thrown in the [PopulateParameterInfoValues](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/76934655be6108c5077be203d9d9ead3cfedb693/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Metadata/DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.Helpers.cs#L278) method of the System.Text.Json library.  It would suggest that the linker is stripping out the parameter names - not sure if that is related to trimming or not.